# Cannot append data fields to database SQL

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc-4

Hi I have a problem I have been trying to pass data to my database mvc 4 project I installed ninject into my project to try and resolve the issue, when I restarted my project all the connection strings were missing from the  xml config file luckily I backed up my project and it renders properly however,

I still have the initial issue to resolve which is this error

**`No parameterless constructor defined for this object`**

I put a parameterless constructor into each controller I have created yet the problem persists any suggestions would be gratefully received as I have to meet a project deadline in one week.  I do have a field countyID in my database for the id parameter in my code could this be the issue would I need to declare this a hidden field?
Thank You!

My Code is

**Controller:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Configuration;
using UnityServiceProject.Models;


namespace UnityServiceProject.Controllers
{
    public class NewAccountController : Controller
    {

        //
        // GET: /NewAccount/

        //public ActionResult Index()
        //{
        //    return View();
        //}

         [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult NewAccount()
        {
            List<SelectListItem> listItem = new List<SelectListItem>();
            NewAccountModel namModel = new NewAccountModel();



            listItem.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "1", Text = "Antrim" }
        );
            listItem.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "2", Text = "Armagh" }
        );
            listItem.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "3", Text = "Carlow" }
        );
            listItem.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "4", Text = "Cavan" }
        );
            listItem.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "5", Text = "Clare" }
        );
            listItem.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "6", Text = "Cork" }
        );
            listItem.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "7", Text = "Derry" }
        );
            listItem.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "8", Text = "Donegal" }
     );
            listItem.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "9", Text = "Down" }
     );
            listItem.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "10", Text = "Dublin" }
     );
            listItem.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "11", Text = "Fermanagh" }
     );
            listItem.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "12", Text = "Galway" }
     );
            listItem.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "13", Text = "Kerry" }
     );
            listItem.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "14", Text = "Kildare" }
     );
            listItem.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "15", Text = "Kilkenny" }
     );
            listItem.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "16", Text = "Laois" }
     );
            listItem.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "17", Text = "Leitrim" }
     );
            listItem.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "18", Text = "Limerick" }
     );
            listItem.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "19", Text = "Longford" }
     );
            listItem.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "20", Text = "Louth" }
     );
            listItem.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "21", Text = "Mayo" }
     );
            listItem.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "22", Text = "Meath" }
     );
            listItem.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "23", Text = "Monaghan" }
     );
            listItem.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "24", Text = "Offaly" }
     );
            listItem.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "25", Text = "Roscommon" }
     );
            listItem.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "26", Text = "Sligo" }
     );
            listItem.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "27", Text = "Tipperary" }
     );
            listItem.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "28", Text = "Tyrone" }
     );
            listItem.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "4", Text = "Waterford" }
     );
            listItem.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "4", Text = "Westmeath" }
     );
            listItem.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "4", Text = "Wexford" }
     );
            listItem.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "4", Text = "Wicklow" }
     );


            namModel.County = new SelectList(listItem, "Value", "Text");
            return View(namModel);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult NewAccount(UnityServiceProject.Models.NewAccountModel newAcc)
        {





           if(ModelState.IsValid)
           {
               using (var db = new UnityServiceEntities())
               {
                   //create New Account entity
                   var adNewAcc = db.AddNewAccounts.Create();

                   adNewAcc.charityName = newAcc.charityName;
                   adNewAcc.charityNumber = newAcc.charityNumber;
                   adNewAcc.addressLine1 = newAcc.addressLine1;
                   adNewAcc.addressLine2 = newAcc.addressLine2;
                   adNewAcc.City = newAcc.City;
                   adNewAcc.County = newAcc.County.SelectedValue.ToString();
                   adNewAcc.Phone = newAcc.Phone;
                   adNewAcc.emailAddress = newAcc.Email;
                   adNewAcc.registeredPassword = newAcc.registeredPassword;
                   adNewAcc.Comments = newAcc.Comments;

                   db.AddNewAccounts.Add(adNewAcc);
                   db.SaveChanges();
                   return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
               }
           }
           return View(newAcc);
        }
        public NewAccountController()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

**Model:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using UnityServiceProject.Models;


namespace UnityServiceProject.Models
{
    public class NewAccountModel
    {
        [Required]
        [StringLength(150)]
        [Display(Name="Charity Name: ")]
        public string charityName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(150)]
        [Display(Name="Charity Number: ")]
        public string charityNumber { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(100)]
        [Display(Name="Address Line 1: ")]
        public string addressLine1 { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(100)]
        [Display(Name="Address Line 2: ")]
        public string addressLine2 { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(100)]
        [Display(Name="City: ")]
        public string City    { get; set; }



        [Required]
        [StringLength(100)]
        [Display(Name = "Select County: ")]
        public SelectList County { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(100)]
        [Display(Name = "Select ID: ")]
        public SelectList countyID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(100)]
        [Display(Name="Phone Number: ")]
        public string Phone { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [EmailAddress]
        [StringLength(150)]//'UserLogin table field' setting max amount of characters  
        [Display(Name = "Registered Email Address: ")]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [StringLength(200)]
        [Display(Name = "Registered Password: ")]
        public string registeredPassword { get; set; }



        [StringLength(300)]
        [Display(Name = "Comments: ")]
        public string Comments { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**cshtml:**

```
@model UnityServiceProject.Models.NewAccountModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "NewAccount";
}

<h2>NewAccount</h2>

@using (@Html.BeginForm()){
@Html.ValidationSummary(true,"Please fill all required fields Thank You.")
<fieldset>
    <legend>Create Account</legend>
    <ol>

        <li>@Html.LabelFor(u => u.charityName)</li>
        <li>@Html.TextBoxFor(u => u.charityName)</li>

        <li>@Html.LabelFor(u => u.charityNumber)</li>
        <li>@Html.TextBoxFor(u => u.charityNumber)</li>

        <li>@Html.LabelFor(u => u.addressLine1)</li>
        <li>@Html.TextBoxFor(u => u.addressLine1)</li>

        <li>@Html.LabelFor(u => u.addressLine2)</li>
        <li>@Html.TextBoxFor(u => u.addressLine2)</li>

        <li>@Html.LabelFor(u => u.City)</li>
        <li>@Html.TextBoxFor(u => u.City)</li>

        <li>@Html.LabelFor(u => u.County)</li>
        <li>@Html.DropDownListFor(model => Model.countyID, Model.County, "Select County: ", new {id = "ddlCounty"})</li>

        <li>@Html.LabelFor(u => u.Phone)</li>
        <li>@Html.TextBoxFor(u => u.Phone)</li>

         <li>@Html.LabelFor(u => u.Email)</li>
        <li>@Html.TextBoxFor(u =>u.Email)</li>

        <li>@Html.LabelFor(u => u.registeredPassword)</li>
        <li>@Html.TextBoxFor(u => u.registeredPassword)</li>

        <li>@Html.LabelFor(u => u.Comments)</li>
        <li>@Html.TextBoxFor(u => u.Comments)</li>
        </ol>
     </fieldset>
    <input type="submit" value="New Account" />
}
```

Answer (score 1):

"No parameterless constructor defined" is a generalized indication that your dependency injection container is *not working properly*. Providing a parameterless constructor is merely glossing over the issue, as you're then effectively not using any dependency injection. You need to look into your DI container configuration and fix any issues there. More than that, I can't say, as you haven't posted your DI container config.